# Macos: Looking for screenshot software with image editing features - that can draw on images - similar to Lightshot

Tags: images, macos, screenshot, highlighting

I am searching for screenshot software for Macos that offers the following functionalities:

- Capture Screenshots: Ability to take screenshots of the whole screen, a specific window, or a custom region.
- Image Annotation: After capturing, I'd like to be able to highlight sections, draw on the screenshot, and add boxes or shapes for emphasis.
- [Optional but beneficial]: A quick share feature that allows sharing the screenshot via a generated link or direct upload to platforms like Imgur.
- [Another optional]: If there are any integrations with other software or cloud storage, that would be a plus.

I am familiar with [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html), which pretty much does what I'm looking for. However, it seems unavailable for macOS at the moment.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in screenshot functionality, which links to Preview inside Quicklook for editing, & also has a Send button right in the window? It will sync to iCloud automatically if your save location is synced.